# Difference between Proterozoic Nagari Quartzite and Gulcheru Quartzite

Tags: stratigraphy, time

The Eparchean Unconformity forms the boundary between Proterozoic Nagari Quartzite and Archean Granite. Now, the Gulcheru Quartzite marks the onset of sedimentation , after Eparchean Unconformity in the Cudappah Basin. So, are 'Proterozoic Nagari Quartzite' and 'Gulcheru Quartzite', the same units?

Comment: Please provide some more context to this question. Where abouts in the world are you talking about for a start? Not everyone is familiar with these units. A map would be very useful if you can provide one.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am talking about the sedimentation process that occurs after the formation of **Eparchean Unconformity** , which is present in **Indian Stratigraphy** of **Pre Cambrian** Time.